# How to print the output in two separate lines?

Tags: java

I've been trying to print the output in two separate lines, I used `System.out.println()` and also `System.out.println("\n")` but I only seem to be getting the last number I enter as the output. I'm guessing this must be easy to work around but would be grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class StoreToArray
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  public static void main(String args [])
  {
    //Access method using object reference        

    StoreToArray t = new StoreToArray();
    t.readFromTerminal(); 
  }

  public void readFromTerminal() {
    System.out.println("Read lines, please enter some other character to stop.");
    String in = input.nextLine();
    int check=0;
    while(true){
            check = input.nextInt();
            if(check == 0){ break;}
            al.add(check);
    }

    for (int i : al) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` is almost always bad code. You want `do { } while (check!=0)` This is also odd anyway as 0 is a valid integer...

Comment: Would `System.out.println(al);` work for you? It has a quite nice formatting. Regarding why only the last is there, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
String in = input.nextLine();
```

is capturing your first number entered and it is never added to the list al.

So, if you enter:

45

40

67

0

the output is:

[40, 67] (using System.out.println(al))

or:

4067 (using your for loop).

Note, the loop is broken by entering 0, not non-numeric characters as the first output text line would suggest.

> Read lines, please enter some other character to stop

should really read

> Read lines, please enter 0 to stop

**[EDIT]**

To add/display numbers to the list correctly:

1) Remove the line:

```
String in = input.nextLine();
```

2) Remove the for loop at the end and replace it with:

```
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: Could you help me add the numbers to the list please? Thank you for the explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a do while and use try and catch. Because when you enter a character instead of a number your program is going to crash.

```
public class StoreToArray
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        //Access method using object reference

        StoreToArray t = new StoreToArray();
        t.readFromTerminal();
    }

    public void readFromTerminal() {
        System.out.println("Read lines, please enter some other character to stop.");
        int check=0;
        do{
            try {
                check = input.nextInt();
                if(check != 0)
                  al.add(check);
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to convert to int.");
                check = 0;
            }    
        }while(check != 0);

        for (int i : al) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, may be this is what you need

```
public void readFromTerminal() {
    System.out
            .println("Read lines, please enter some other character to stop.");
    int check = 0;
    while (true) {
        check = input.nextInt();
        al.add(check);
        if (check == 0) {
            break;
        }

    }

    for (int i : al) {
        System.out.print(i+ "\n");
    }
}
```